# How do I SUM a column in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to import a CSV file as a list in Python.  I then want to take one of the columns and sum it to find a total for that particular column.

The code I'm using (including parts I have commented out) is written below. I've also included the image of the CSV file I'm working with.

[image]

Code:

```
import csv

    f = open('cars.csv', 'r')

    reader = csv.reader(f)

    cars = []

    for row in reader:
        try:

            cars.append([int(row[2])])
        except:
            pass

    total = sum(cars)

    print(total)
```

Comment: `cars.append(int(row[2]))`?

Comment: Thanks to all that helped out with this.  It was most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

"Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings"

So your code should be:

```
sum = 0
with open("cars.csv") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        sum += int(row[2])
return sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small change:

```
cars.append(int(row[2]))
```

By writing `[int(row[2])]`, you were appending a list to the list `cars`. Thus while summing, it was giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple comprehension and sum function.

First read data to list.
Then use `sum` on column 2 like this.

```
import csv

with open('cars.csv', newline='') as f:
  table = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')) #if you have other delimiter then change parameter
  result = sum([int(row[2]) for row in table])
  #do stuff on result
```